# Container DIV background image not expanding with content

Tags: css, html, height, background-image

I am having trouble with my container div, which you will see below.  It contains a very simple graphic that repeats vertically. I want the background image to expand with the content, however it is not doing so.  When I expand my browser window, the background image expands to fill the page vertically, as it should...but when I scroll, the lower portion of the background that was initially below the fold, is empty when I scroll down.

I've also included the html,body as I am not sure where the problem is.

[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE PAGE I AM HAVING TROUBLE WITH](http://atomcrayon.com/client/100miletriathlon/TEMPLATE.html)

Thank you!!!

```
html,body {
    background-color: #999;
    background-image: url(../images/bg.jpg);
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(../images/bg_container.gif);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 860px;
    padding: 0 3px 0 3px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: can u give a fiddle ?

Comment: OK, this is my first fiddle.  Actually had to google that.  My apologies.  I am a designer, not much of a programmer...but am OK with HTML and CSS.  Hope this is what you need.  

http://jsfiddle.net/R8aZS/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you are using `position:absolute` on the div `id="triathlete"` then your main container doesn't take in care the space of that element. The solution you can try is this:

- In your html change the order between two elements, you have:

  ```
  <div id="triathlete"></div>
  <div id="mainBody"></div>
  ```

  Change those elements like this :

  ```
  <div id="mainBody"></div>
  <div id="triathlete"></div>
  ```
- Then remove the `position:absolute` :

  ```
  #triathlete {
    background-image: url(../images/image_triathlete.png);
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    left: 3px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 87px 30px 0 30px;
    /*position: absolute; Remove this
    top: 363px;*/
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  ```
- And change the `height` for the container to `min` :

  ```
  #container {
    min-height:100%;
  }
  ```

The [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R8aZS/1/)

Comment: I cannot possibly thank you enough!!!  I spent over 2 hours last night trying to figure this out on my own!!

Comment: @AtomCrayon No problem my friend glad to help you . I am graphic designer too as a recommendation avoid use `position:Absolute` to make the entire layout use floats and inline-blocks in most cases.

Comment: I will certainly take that advice. Its about time to do some serious brushing up on some CSS3 skills!

Answer (score 0):

If this doesn't work (for any reason), or you feel like implementing it gives you too much or a headache, here is a quick and dirty fix using jQuery:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("#container").css("height",$(document).height());
},50);
```

This will automatically resize your container div to envelop all of it's contents, even if they are absolutely positioned.

Noting again, this is not the proper way to solve a problem like this, but might help you if you don't have time to do it the right way.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this one too. For this current site I am working, I just may do it this way this once.  I was supposed to have this site finished over the weekend!